# Mission Control covered by copy of background

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, mission-control

This happens whenever I plug my MacBook into a thunderbolt display. Mission Control seems to be stuck like this until I restart. Does anyone know a fix? Has anyone at least seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mission Control has several major bugs, including this one (still). You should be able to remedy the issue without rebooting by issuing a simple Terminal command:

launch Terminal from /Applications/Utilities/ and type the following command:

```
killall Dock
```

The Dock and all subprocesses will restart themselves automatically, including Mission Control.